# Problem with revealing a hidden folder

Tags: terminal, macos

I have a problem. I used command `chflags hidden` to hide a folder named `!_TRANSCODE`. Now I'm trying to undo this by typing `chflags no hidden !_TRANSCODE` and I get this error: `-bash: !_TRANSCODE: event not found`

```
Last login: Tue Nov 15 13:12:47 on ttys000
Marks-iMac:~ StefanCzapla$ cd /Volumes/THE_REASON_MASTER_1
Marks-iMac:THE_REASON_MASTER_1 StefanCzapla$ ls
!_TRANSCODE 03.02.16 Stock Footage
02.23.16                03.03.16                The Reason VFX.zip
02.24.16                03.04.16                test
02.25.16                03.05.16                vfx
02.26.16                1,001 Sound FX          voiceover
02.27.16                Music
03.01.16                Project 
Marks-iMac:THE_REASON_MASTER_1 StefanCzapla$ chflags nohidden !_TRANSCODE
-bash: !_TRANSCODE: event not found
Marks-iMac:THE_REASON_MASTER_1 StefanCzapla$
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

You should escape the `!`.

Try:

```
chflags nohidden \!_TRANSCODE
```

`!` is a special character to bash, it is used to refer to previous commands. A more extensive explanation can be found at: [What is “-bash: !”: event not found"](https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found)